# How to call this func code snippet?

Tags: c#, func

I am looking at this article on monads:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx

I am writing the code in my copy of VS2010, but for the following code:

```
public static Func<T, V> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, V> f, Func<T, U> g)
{
    return x => f(g(x));
}
```

How do I call this?

Also, the article states:

> Function composition takes two functions and plumbs the result from the second function into the input of the first function, thereby forming one function.

Is this not just pipelines?

The code sample:

```
var r = f.Compose(g)(x);
```

Does not compile.

Also, what

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by how do you call this? How to call `Compose()` or how to use composite function calls? And the compiler doesn't just stay silent and not compile your code. What does it say that prevents it from compiling?

Comment: How are your `g` and `x` defined? Also, is this type of syntax useful beyond obfuscation? Seems like a lot of trouble and indirection to simply chain two function calls together.

Comment: I mwan how to call the method itself. I defined g and x as ints and then made the call  var r = Compose(g, x);

Comment: There's your problem. `g` and `x` are supposed to be functions that accept certain types, not value types i.e. simple ints.

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is **not a forum**. If you have comments on people's answers, that's fine, but if you want to add additional information *to the question*, you should use the **`edit`** button to do so. Also, if you're going to tell people that their code doesn't work, it helps if you actually copy their code correctly...

Comment: If you want to add a comment that won't fit in a comment block, you should just update your question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work? Note that the Extension method has to be in a public static class and the method itself must be static.

```
public static class FunctionalExtensions
{
    public static Func<T, V> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, V> f, Func<T, U> g)
    {
        return x => f(g(x));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<double, double> 
            f1 = Square,         // Func<double, double> is a delegate type so we have to create
            g1 = AddOne,         // an instance for both f and g
            h1 = f1.Compose(g1); // This is a Func<double, double> now, (i.e. h(X) = f(g(x)) )

        // To call new function do this
        double result1 = h1(5.0);

        Func<double, double>
            f2 = x => x*x,       
            g2 = x => x + 1,       
            h2 = f2.Compose(g2);

        // To call new function do this
        double result2 = h2(5.0);
    }

    public static double Square(double x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }

    public static double AddOne(double x)
    {
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```

Also notice that f1: double -> double and g1: double -> double.

In the compose function

f: V -> U  and g: U -> T

so f.g: V -> T

In other words in my example, not all types had to be double. You just have to make sure that the domain of
the function f (the outer function) includes the range of the function g (the inner function). In programming
this means that the return type of g needs to be the same as (or implicitly cast to) the parameter type of f.

Comment: That doesn't work, no. I pasted that as is into a class called test, whcich is static and changed f.Compose into test.Compose

Comment: Try it now. Extension methods have to be in a static class.

Comment: this should work, if you can add some explanation it'll be better for future reference. gets +1 for simplicity.

Comment: I added some comments, and a note about types and composing functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    // Note extension methods need to be defined in a static class
    public static Func<T, V> Compose<T, U, V>(this Func<U, V> f, Func<T, U> g)
    {
        return x => f(g(x));
    }
}

public class CallingClass
{
    public void CallingMethod()
    {
        Func<string, int> f1 = s => int.Parse(s);
        Func<int, double> f2 = i => i / 2.0;

        // Note which way round f1 and f2 go
        Func<string, double> composed = f2.Compose(f1);

        var result = composed("3");

        // Now result == 1.5
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a fuller code sample which shows what the containing class should look like?

Comment: It has to be the other way around. Right now you are calling f2(f1("3")); which is int.Parse((i/2.0)), but f1 expects a string, and f2 returns a double. It should be f1.Compose(f2); string => int => double.

Comment: @Joseph no, this code runs as expected and returns `1.5`. Look at the definition of `Compose` : during the execution of the function that `Compose` returns, first `g` is invoked, then `f` is invoked on the result. That is, it invokes the NON `this` argument to `Compose` first, then the `this` argument. Hence, `f1` THEN `f2`. I have run this code.